# how to implement oncheck event of td on one2many list view

Tags: javascript, events, checkbox, odoo, odoo-10

I have added a checkbox to my one2many field listview(using the **web_one2many_selectable_10** module) I want to get every id of the selected line in my one2many field oncheck of the check box instead of onclick of the "Create DR" button

[image: one2many checkbox]

is it possible to have an onchange event on the checkbox in my one2many table?

here's the javascript code

```
odoo.define('web_one2many_selectable_10.form_widgets', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var core = require('web.core');
    var form_common = require('web.form_common');
    var _t = core._t;
    var QWeb = core.qweb;
    var Model = require('web.Model');
    var FieldOne2Many = core.form_widget_registry.get('one2many');


    var One2ManySelectable = FieldOne2Many.extend({
        // my custom template for unique char field
        template: 'One2ManySelectable', 

        multi_selection: true,
        //button click
        events: {
            "click td.o_list_record_selector": "get_id_lines",
        },
        start: function() 
        {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var self=this;          
           },
        get_id_lines: function(e){
            var self=this;
            console.log('im here')

        },
        //collecting the selected IDS from one2manay list
        get_selected_ids_one2many: function ()
        {
            var ids =[];
            this.$el.find('td.o_list_record_selector input:checked')
                    .closest('tr').each(function () {

                        ids.push(parseInt($(this).context.dataset.id));
                        console.log(ids);
            });
            return ids;
        },


    });
    // register unique widget, because Odoo does not know anything about it
    //you can use <field name="One2many_ids" widget="x2many_selectable"> for call this widget
    core.form_widget_registry.add('one2many_selectable', One2ManySelectable);
});
```

When I change the code

```
events: {
            "click td.o_list_record_selector": "get_id_lines",
        },
```

to

```
events: {
            "click th.o_list_record_selector": "get_id_lines",
        },
```

it is working fine but when i also check the checkbox in the td of the table it wont call the **get_id_lines** function it's only working when i check the checkbox on the thead part of the table

Comment: try to access like this:- events: {
            "click .o_list_record_selector": "get_id_lines",
        },

Comment: @DipenShah this also didn't work thanks for the answer tho

Comment: it would be better you can add your XML file code too.